# Visual Basic - Reading .txt, Splitting, Sorting and Displaying

Tags: arrays, file, visual-studio-2008, console

I'm rather new to visual basic and I'm making a text based game for a little project in my spare time. The game will have a scoring system, at the end of the game the user's score will be stored in a text file. I haven't written the code to write to the file although im sure appending text isn't difficult. The problem I'm having is displaying the high scores; I can read them in, I can use Split(","), I have even displayed the results in a nice table. The problem I am having is displaying the high scores in order of the actual scores. 
This is the code i have to build the score table.(NOTE. Pad() is a function i made to pad spaces to the end of strings, this is so they fit into the table correctly. sytax: Pad(string,length of output))

```
    Dim FStrm As FileStream
    Dim StrmR As StreamReader
    FStrm = New FileStream("HighScores.txt", FileMode.Open)
    StrmR = New StreamReader(FStrm)
    Dim highScores As New List(Of String)

    While StrmR.Peek <> -1
        highScores.Add(StrmR.ReadLine)
    End While

    FStrm.Close()

    Console.WriteLine("       __________________________________________________________________ ")
    Console.WriteLine("      |       Score       |       Name                                   |")
    Console.WriteLine("      |-------------------|----------------------------------------------|")
    Dim Scores() As String
    For Each score As String In highScores
        Scores = score.Split(",")
        Console.WriteLine("      |  {0}  |  {1}    |", Pad(Scores(0), 15), Pad(Scores(1), 40))
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("      |___________________|______________________________________________| ")
```

The following is an example of the text file.

```
2,Zak
10000,Charlie
9999,Shane
90019,Rebecca
```

Could somebody please help me find a way to sort the lines by the score, maybe I need to take a completely different approach? Thank you very much!

-Charlie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a C# guy, but here goes:

```
Dim scores As List(Of UserScore)
Dim lines As String()
'Read in all lines in one hit.
lines = File.ReadAllLines("HighScores.txt")
scores = New List(Of UserScore)

For Each line As String In lines
    Dim tokens As String()
    'Split each line on the comma character.
    tokens = line.Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    'Create a new UserScore class and assign the properties.
    Dim userScore As UserScore
    userScore = New UserScore()
    userScore.Name = tokens(1)
    userScore.Score = Int32.Parse(tokens(0))

    'Add to the list of UserScore objects.
    scores.Add(userScore)
Next

'Sort them by descending order of score. To sort in the other
'direction, remove the Descending keyword.
scores = (From s In scores Order By s.Score Descending).ToList()
```

You'll need this class to hold the values. I have assumed that the `Score` will always be an integer - if it is something else then this field and the `Int32.Parse` call will need to be adjusted to suit.

```
Class UserScore
    Property Name As String
    Property Score As Int32
End Class
```

Depending on how robust this needs to be, you may also want to check that the file opens successfully, the `Int32.Parse` call works (the `TryParse` method would be better in this case) and that the `line.Split` call returns an array with two values. Otherwise, that should do the trick.